# NHibernate How to map foreign key relationship to multiple properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, rdbms

I'm using NHibernate as my ORM for a personal project of mine. I have a Postgre SQL database for storage and I'm trying to map a Many-To-One relationship between the tables.

I have a web_exception table that look like this

```
CREATE TABLE logging.web_exception
(
    web_exception_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('logging.web_exception_web_exception_id_seq'::regclass),
    query_string character varying(2048) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    form text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    cookies text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    session text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    headers text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    exception text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    url character varying(2048) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    application_id integer,
    CONSTRAINT web_exception_pkey PRIMARY KEY (web_exception_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_web_exception_application FOREIGN KEY (application_id)
        REFERENCES public.application (application_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

I'm trying to map it to my WebException class that looks like this.

```
public class WebException
{
    public virtual int WebExceptionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string QueryString { get; set; }
    public virtual string Form { get; set; }
    public virtual string Cookies { get; set; }
    public virtual string Session { get; set; }
    public virtual string Headers { get; set; }
    public virtual string Exception { get; set; }
    public virtual string Url { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

I have run into an issue mapping the class with both the `ApplicationId` and the `Application` property. Both properties represent the foreign key to the `application` table I have defined in the database. One is obviously just the integer primary key value and the other is the entire entity representing a row in that table. In my mappings I have

```
Property(
    we => we.ApplicationId,
    m => m.Column(c => c.Name("application_id"))
);
ManyToOne(we => we.Application, mto => mto.Column("application_id"));
```

It looks like this causes NHibernate to think that properties should be mapped to 2 separate columns. I get this exception message, which is generated from NHibernates internals, when trying to save it to the database.

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

When I remove the `ManyToOne` mapping saving the record works just fine. However I would like the flexibility of having both properties. i.e. being able to simply set the `ApplicationId` property on save to create a relationship between the tables and being able to bring back the entire `Application` class as a member of the `WebException` class when needed. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ManyToOne(we => we.Application, mto => { mto.Column("application_id")
                                         mto.Class(typeof(Application));
                                         mto.Update(false);
                                         mto.Insert(false);
                                         mto.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
  });
```